# How to secure the software application in a single board arm computer?

Tags: security, arm, embedded-linux, code-access-security

We had developed an application in C language. We then cross compiled it and have it port over to an ARM Single Board Computer that is running Linux. We are starting to sell this SBC to customers for their specific needs using this application. However, we heard rumors that they are also trying to hack into the SBC to copy our compiled code and then to decompile it so that in the future they will develop their own. 
So my question is: How to protect my software application in the SBC? 
We had tried standard Linux software protection solution such as truecrypt but it is difficult to cross compile to the SBC. Any suggestions? 
Best regards,
new2RoR

Comment: Maybe [security.se](http://security.stackexchange.com) would be a better forum for this.

Comment: Don't waste your time.  If they want to reverse engineer it, they will.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have two separate issues to deal with here:

1. Disclosure of confidential information (e.g. details of the implementation of your software)
2. Unauthorised use/modification of your software

The only entirely reliable solution to both is using a SBC with secure boot, and fully trusted execution path (e.g. everything code-signed).  This is by no means impossible, but will limit your hardware choices and be high-effort.   This is fundamentally contrary to the ethos of the open source movement, and solutions are hard to come by.

Dealing with the issue of confidentiality, disassembling compiled C and C++ is not particularly easy or useful and requires a fairly high level of skill; it won't be an economic attack unless the value of doing so is very high.

Unless you can prevent the attacker getting access to the binary form of the software,  you can reduce the attack surface and make life more difficult for any attacker by:

- Stripping symbols
- Obfuscating those symbols that need to remain
- Statically link with libraries.
- Obfuscation or encryption of any data compiled into the software

Preventing unauthorised usage can be achieved by some kind of authentication with something a legitimate user holds and/or code signing

- Code signing can be used to prevent modified versions of the software being used (so long as you trust the operating system to enforce it)
- Using a hardware authentication token or unique identity device can ensure the software isn't copied and used on another system.

In practice, you probably want both of these.